# OnTriggerEnter increase the colliding object size?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a simple cube, which's collider I am using as a invisible wall ( border ), to which I have attached the script below, so when an other object ( let say Object A ) hit it - it should be sent to a specific point ( Globals.ornamentsCreationPoint ). Yet, instead - the size of the "Object A" increase ginormous and it is not sent to the specific point.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class OuterBordersCollider : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnTriggerEnter( Collider other )
    {

        other.gameObject.transform.SetParent( Globals.ornamentsCreationPoint.transform, false );
        other.gameObject.transform.position = Globals.ornamentsCreationPoint.transform.position;
        other.gameObject.transform.gameObject.AddComponent<Rigidbody>(); //?

    }
}
```

- Why the object size increase ?
- How can I send the colliding object "Object A" to Globals.ornamentsCreationPoint.transform.position on collision ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say for sure based on only that bit of code, but since you are changing the parent with `.setParent()`, that might have something to do with it.

Since an object inherits the size of its parent, perhaps the moment you parent it, the (perhaps larger) scale of the parent applies and thus it appears as if the object itself had its scale increased.

Comment: With or without it - it doesnt make change. the "other" - which is the colliding object still grow in size.

Comment: As @ClockworkOnion said, if the parent has a bigger scale it now applies to the child so it grows. You are setting the `other`'s parent so it makes sense, plus, you are setting worldPositionStays to false, so it **DOES** apply the new scale. Try setting that true.You can Check that or any references to scale. If that doesnt work try giving more context.

Comment: Thank You fellows ! This was actually helpful. It turns out it was an other collider playing trics due bad script,  but your answers helped. ! :)